# Replace a string using re.sub only if prefix and suffix matches

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to convert German words to English using custom dictionary.
In below code, replace should only happen if the suffix or prefix of the matching word falls in characters

```
[,\/!?()_1234567890-=+."""' "]
```

For example:

`Mein` should be converted at first but not in `MeinName` as the prefix and suffix are not characters mentioned above. If there were single words like `_Mein` or `Mein.` they need to be converted.

```
import re

string = "Mein ,Name, ist John, Wo23 bist+ ,_du? , MeinName "
replacements = {
    'Mein': 'my',
    'ist': 'is',
    'Wo': 'where',
    'bist': 'are',
    'du': 'you',
    'is': 'iis'
}
re.sub(
    '({})'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, replacements.keys()))),
    lambda m: replacements[m.group()],
    string
)
```

Expected output:

```
my ,name,is John,where23 are+,_you? ,MeinName
```

Comment: Your expected output does not match your rules: `is234` has a `2` after ``is``, so, it should be replaced with `is`. Where does `_` disappear before `du` in the output?

Comment: For now, try `rx = r'(?:{})(?=[,/!?()_0-9\-=+."\s\'])'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, replacements.keys())))`

Comment: @wiktor Edited the expected output.

Comment: Ok, does  https://ideone.com/3Rn0m1 work for you?

Comment: its working.Thanks @ Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
s = "Mein ,Name, ist John, Wo23 bist+ ,_du? , MeinName "
replacements = { "Mein": "my", "ist": "is", "Wo":"where", "bist":"are", "du":"you", "is" :"iis"}
rx = r'(?:{})(?=[,/!?()_0-9\-=+."\s\'])'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, replacements.keys())))
print (rx)
print ( re.sub(rx, lambda m: replacements[m.group()], s) )
# => my ,Name, is John, where23 are+ ,_you? , MeinName
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3Rn0m1).

The regex will look like

```py
(?:Mein|ist|Wo|bist|du|is)(?=[,/!?()_0-9\-=+."\s\'])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yD7VTr/1). Details:

- `(?:Mein|ist|Wo|bist|du|is)` - one of the alternative strings
- `(?=[,/!?()_0-9\-=+."\s\'])` - a positive lookahead matching a location that is immediately followed with `,`, `/`, `!`, `?`, `)`, `(`, `_`, a digit, `-`, `=`, `+`, `.`, `"`, whitespace and `'`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for the answer. I was unaware of lookahead/lookbehind concept. Here I used both positive lookahead and lookbehind and able to achieve desired result.